# Add legend to ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggmap

I am trying to add a legend to a plot generated by ggmap package in R. The dataset I am working with is

```
    Latitude  Longitude  amount
    61.37072 -152.40442  436774
    32.80667  -86.79113 3921030
    34.96970  -92.37312 1115087
    33.72976 -111.43122 5068957
```

The code I am using is

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

MyMap <- get_map(location = c(lon = -96.5, lat = 40.68925), zoom = 4,maptype = "terrain", scale = 2)
ggmap(MyMap)+ 
geom_point(data = data,aes(x = Longitude , y = Latitude ),size=sqrt(data$amount)/800,col='darkred', shape = 19,alpha = .5)
```

[image]

Now I want to add legend to this plot. The legend should show the sizes of the circles on the map correspond to certain amount. How can I do it?

Comment: Try to put "size" to inside aes-funktion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `size` argument should be included within the `aes()` section of the `geom_point` function, as follows:

```
plot <- ggmap(MyMap) + 
  geom_point(data = data,aes(x = Longitude , y = Latitude, size=amount), col='darkred', shape = 19,alpha = .5)
plot
```

[image]

If you want to have further customisation of the scale, you can use the optional argument `scale_size_area()` to choose the [breaks and labels](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_size.html) for the legend. For example:

```
plot +  scale_size_area(breaks = c(436774, 1115087, 4000000, 5068957),
          labels = c("436774", "1115087", "4000000", "5068957"))
```

[image]

**Change Point Size**:

If you want to adjust the size of the points, you are better off using the `scale_size` function, which lets you specify a range:

```
plot +  scale_size(range = c(5,9))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mikey, your code works for me. But I have a further question. Is it possible to customize the size of the circles on the map?  I want to compare the data across different years. But the sizes of the circles remain almost the same.

Comment: I've updated the answer for you :) you could also consider something like `scale_size(range = c(5,9), limits = c(0,10000000))` . Please mark this answer as accepted if you have found it useful.