# r ggmap - add annotation superimposed on map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

Questions about map legend editing exist ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47253773/add-legend-to-ggmap)), but not exactly what I need.

Using ggmap, how do I select points in a map and add annotations superimposed on the map? Take the following code:

```
Map <- get_map(location = 'Santiago, Chile', zoom = 6, maptype = "terrain")
Map <- ggmap(Map)
Points <- data.frame(lon=c(-71.82718,-71.31263),lat=c(-34.36935,-34.29322))
Map_Points <- Map + geom_point(data = Points,aes(x=lon,y=lat,size=6))
```

[image: Chile + two points]

So now I have a nice map with a few points. How do I write some annotation near one of the points?

Comment: Do you mean an annotation near a point on the map? Or the legend next to the map?

Comment: I mean the former, an annotation next to one of the points superimposed on the map. (Are annotations and legends different things?)

Comment: My interpretation is that legend explains the representation/encoding of data, while annotation is data as text. I think you want to add a column with labels to your data, then use something like `geom_text` ou `geom_label` to put your annotaions. You can add `ggrepel` if you want clean look, but it should'nt be needed with 2 points. Also there might be specific paxkage for ggplot annotations, I think it exists even though I never used one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite straightforward:
[image: 1]

#### Code

```
library(ggrepel)                   # for the auto-repelling label
Map + 
    geom_point(data = Points, 
               aes(x = lon, y = lat),
               size = 3) +
    geom_label_repel(data = Points, 
                     aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = name),
                     size = 3,
                     vjust = -2,
                     hjust = 1)
```

#### Data

```
library(tmaptools)                 # for the geocode lookup
library(ggmap)
santiago_coords <- rbind(as.numeric(paste(geocode_OSM("Santiago, Chile")$coords))) 
Map <- get_map(location = santiago_coords, zoom = 6, maptype = "terrain")
Map <- ggmap(Map)
Points <- data.frame(lon=c(-71.82718,-71.31263),
                     lat=c(-34.36935,-34.29322),
                     name=c("Location One", "Location Two"))
```